# Content above RecyclerView with parallax effect in Android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, parallax, android-appbarlayout

As described in [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CidlM.png), I want to implement a Layout where half the screen is some `Content`, f.e. a `LinearLayout` including a pie chart.
The other half of the screen should be a `RecyclerView` including a `CardView` which I already implemented.
When scrolling up there should be a Parallax Effect hiding the `Content`up to the `AppBar`.

I tried to use `LinearLayouts` (where one includes the `Content` and one includes the `Recyclerview`) with a `weightSum` but it did not work properly.

How can I implement this properly?

[Design that I want to implement in my App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CidlM.png)

Comment: @MartinZeitler I didn't ask for specific code. I would be happy with a description/an approach of how I can implement it. As I wrote, I already tried Linear Layouts with layout-weight and parallax effect. I would upload the code belonging to that particular problem, but for now I only have the RecyclerView, because I have no approach for the problem at the moment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with the other answer here. Take a look at the docs.

But for a quick fix,

First, import the android Design Library

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
```

You must already be having the CardView and RecyclerView libraries

```
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
```

Then implement this code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Main3Activity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/Base.ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="350dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:contentScrim="#0e0d0e"
            app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@android:color/transparent">

            <!--these views are only to illustrate the imp. tags -->
            <!--that you need to implement in your views-->
            <!--in the "Component" area-->

            <!--start example-->

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:contentDescription="@null"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                app:title="Title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>

            <!--end example-->

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/nestedScrollView"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1200dp">

            <!--implement the RecyclerView here-->

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scrollbars="vertical">

            </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>


        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: @C Forge Thank you, this works fine! Allthough I just found out, that my biggest problem was not not knowing how to implement this, but much more not being able to test properly, since I migrated to AndroidX and Gradle Version 28 where all the Support Library references don't work. It took me a while to find all the new libraries